# (Except when thrown from:) checkbox gets unchecked when restarting Visual Studio 2022

Tags: exception, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

I have been getting an unexpected `System.NullReferenceException` when filling HTML form attributes in a view using a for loop.

At the time of the error the program breaks and shows this prompt:

[Error image prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSh71.png)

When I check the exception when thrown from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll` checkbox the program stops throwing this error. However when I restart Visual Studio 2022 the box gets unchecked and I have to check it manually all over again.

How could I make it remain checked ?

I am working with ASP.NET Core 7 MVC.

Comment: It seems like you are dealing with a debugging issue in Visual Studio 2022. The behavior you're describing, where the checkbox for "Except when thrown from: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll" is getting unchecked after restarting Visual Studio, might be related to the Visual Studio settings or project configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem fixed in: Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8.x**

After checking out [Qiang Fu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20240963/qiang-fu) answer, I stumbled upon the solution. In  [Microsoft's Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Conditions-in-Exception-settings-lost-af/10429878?space=8&q=resharper&sort=newest) the user David Funk reports the same bug :

> when I add conditions to an exception this is only persistent for the
> current Visual Studio instance. I.e. after restarting Visual Studio
> the exceptions are gone again.

The feedback bot informs him that the issue has been solved in the last version released (version 17.8.x).

So **in order to solve this issue you just need to update Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.8.x or above**, for me it worked just fine as I was working in version 17.4.x.

Answer (score 1):

According to this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022#add-and-delete-exceptions

> Exception settings are persisted in the solution's .suo file, so they apply to a particular solution.

So make sure `.suo` file is not deleted or reset. (".vs" is a hidden folder)
[image]

Comment: Thank you Qiang Fu for checking it out. Sadly, the .suo file is intact.

Comment: @nikoleta_xvs emmm, this file could be automatically regenerated if delete. Intact doesn't mean it hasn't been reset.. I have tested the .suo truely storage the exception settings.